# Explosion of solution with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, stochastic-calculus

I'm trying to solve a delayed ODE involving white noise with the help of NDSolve. This provides a reasonable solution for times between 0 and 20000. After that the solution seems to explode. A curious fact is that for different noises (and thus for different solutions), the explosion always occur short after 20000.

I suspect that this is caused by a numerical problem, and I would like to ask if anyone has an idea how to solve it. Also I would like to ask if it is possible to know which method is used by NDSolve to solve the equation (this might help to understand how to solve the problem).
Here is my code:

```
discnoise = TimeSeries[RandomFunction[WhiteNoiseProcess[], {0, 100000}]]
randomnoise = Interpolation[discnoise]; 
\[Tau] = 42.904989430228234; 
T = 35.33300464418786; 
nmax = 20000; 
Bmin = 1; 
Bmax = 10; 
Nd = 8.4; 
\[CapitalOmega] = -Nd/\[Tau]^2; 
f[x_] := (x/4)*(1 + Erf[x^2 - Bmin^2])*(1 - Erf[x^2 - Bmax^2])
sol1 = NDSolve[{Derivative[2][x][t] + x[t]/\[Tau]^2 + 2*(Derivative[1][x][t]/\[Tau]) == \[CapitalOmega]*f[x[t - T]] + 0.008*randomnoise[t], 
     x[t /; t <= 0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, nmax}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", MaxSteps -> 100000];
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: In the `NDSolve` you ask for a solution that is valid in the range `{t, 0, nmax}` and you have set `nmax` to `20000`. You should not expect reasonable results beyond `20000`. Also, if you think there may be precision issues, you should not introduce machine precision numbers. Any calculation that includes a machine precision number will be done at machine precision, i.e., precision is neither tracked nor controlled. Either use `Rationalize` or `SetPrecision` to avoid machine precision. Set `WorkingPrecision` in functions that take that option.

Comment: Dear @BobHanlon, thank you for your comment! I just set nmax=20000 because NDSolve provides a reasonable solution in this range. If one sets nmax to higher values, an "explosion" of the solution will occur. I will try to use WorkingPrecision, thanks!